# Dynamically add input field in typescript - after on-click - typescript

Tags: typescript, input-field

I am looking for a code solution that dynamically adds a section/ input field after clicking a button. It would be an additional solution if the same could be provided to remove the input field.

Comment: Please remove the `types`, `typescript-typings` and `typescript2.0` tags and show what code you have so far in attempt to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not even a typescript question, but here you go, this is written in vanilla ts.

```
//index.ts
document.getElementById("app")!.innerHTML = `
<button id="btn">Press to add</button>
`;

const onClick = () =>
  document.getElementById("app")!.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));

document.getElementById("btn")!.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```html
<head>
    <title>This is no ts Question</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.ts">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```